# How to deploy .Net Core publish files on Apache sever

Tags: apache, asp.net-core

I am exploring .Net core 2.0 have created sample web api project in using VS2017 and deployed on Apache web server, but it is not running from Apache however running fine when deployed on IIS.

Am I missing something in publish configuration? currently I can see dlls and folder by the name 'runtime' with subfolders 'unix', 'win', 'win7'.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your Apache server running on Window, a Linux distribution or Mac Server? Do any of the [following details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache) help? (I found that link be Google/Bing searching ".NET Core Publish Apache" what did you search?)

Comment: Currently Apache is running on Windows 10 machine. I am exploring what is Prerequisites "Server running CentOS 7 with a standard user account with sudo privilege"